# How to combine array by a comon value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => phone_calls
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_delete
            [1] => can_delete
            [requirment] => 000000000100000
            [2] => 000000000100000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => phone_calls
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_insert
            [1] => can_insert
            [requirment] => 000000000001000
            [2] => 000000000001000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => phone_calls
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_purge
            [1] => can_purge
            [requirment] => 000000000010000
            [2] => 000000000010000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => phone_calls
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_update
            [1] => can_update
            [requirment] => 000000000000100
            [2] => 000000000000100
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => accounts
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_use
            [1] => can_use
            [requirment] => 000000000000001
            [2] => 000000000000001
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [section_name] => accounts
            [0] => phone_calls
            [permission_key] => can_view
            [1] => can_view
            [requirment] => 000000000000010
            [2] => 000000000000010
        )

)
```

I want it to look like this

```
Array
(
    [phone_calls] => Array
        (
            [can_update] => 4
            [can_insert] => 8
            [can_purge] => 16
            [can_delete] => 32
        )

    [accounts] => Array
        (
            [can_use] => 1
            [can_view] => 2
        )

)
```

the common factor here is the values of "section_name" as long as the "secton_name" is the same then the permission_key and the requirement go in the same bucket.

In this example, there are 2 distinct section_name (ie. phone_calls, accounts) so the final array should have 2 keys (ie. phone_calls, accounts)

Here is what I have tried so far

```
$rules = getSystemRules();

$rulesTotal = count($rules);
$finalArray = array();
$subArray = array();

for($i=0; $i < $rulesTotal; ++$i){
    $row = $rules[$i];
    /** if section_name = the previous section_name then put the the "permission_key" and the "requirment"
    *   in the same array $subArray. Else take the $subArray and put it into a new array called $finalArray
    *   and make they key for the $finalArray the section_name
    */
    if($i == 0 || ($i > 0 && $row['section_name'] == $rules[$i-1]['section_name'])){
        $subArray[$row['permission_key']] = bindec($row['requirment']);

    } else {

        $finalArray[$rules[$i-1]['section_name']][] = $subArray;
        $subArray = array();
        $subArray[$row['permission_key']] = bindec($row['requirment']);
    }
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

This is the query that I user to get the `$rules` array

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE section_name, permission_key, requirement
FROM permission_rules
ORDER BY section_name
```

But this code is not working like I expect. The `$finalArray` is always empty

Comment: Perhaps a slight change to your SQL query could give you a format closer to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
foreach($rules as $rule) {
    $result[$rule['section_name']][$rule['permission_key']] = bindec($rule['requirement']);
}
```

Given the array you could use `$rule[0]` etc... as well.